# extract file on remote server without SSH access

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh

The following works as expected:

```
# mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | mysql -h192.168.50.51 mysql -uroot -pPassWord someDB
```

This works as well:

```
# mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | gzip | ssh 192.168.50.51 "gunzip | mysql -uroot -pPassWord someDB"
```

But when I do not have SSH access to the remote server, how to I extract data? 
This does not work::

`# mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | gzip | "gunzip | mysql -uroot -pPassWord someDB`"

Comment: What all I need to do is to compress and send data (faster!)

Comment: Not necessarily if the data is binary!  Compression might result in a size larger than the original.

Comment: Is it possible to perform a remote mysql connection perhaps? That would simplify things greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gzip and gunzip is only sending data faster over the ssh connection.  It is not loading any data into mysql faster, it's fully uncompressed when the mysql command to load it is invoked.

Try one of the following:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | mysql -uroot -pPassWord someDB
```

or, to use compression to speed up the transfer directly between the client and the server (if both the client and server support it) try:

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | mysql -uroot -pPassWord --compress someDB
```

The second is the same as the first, but added '--compress' to the mysql client.

Source: [mysql command options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_compress)

Comment: How do I know if both servers support compression?

Comment: The way I check is by attempting a compressed connection, and issuing the 'status' command.  When compression is enabled I see a line that says: 'Protocol:  Compressed'.  When compression is not enabled, that line is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you really must, there's always the old standby: copy and paste (yes, really):

`mysqldump -uroot -pPasswd central conc_passenger --no-create-info --compact | gzip | base64`

and then put the output of that command in place of `B64DATA` in:

`echo 'B64DATA' | base64 -id | zcat | mysql -uroot -pPasswd someDB`

and run that on the remote host.  Yes, there are better ways, but when you just need to move a few dozen KB from one place to another and each window is at the end of six cascaded terminal sessions, capitalizing on the fact that you already have the two windows side-by-side in your GUI can be a lifesaver.

Comment: The argument length is normally 1/4 the stack size, on EL6 that would be 2.5mb. I suspect that the output of the command will exceed this.

Comment: @MIfe Good point!  Big enough for a 10+ MB database, given that we're compressing.  But yes, for bigger sizes, simply throw the base64 data into a file on the destination side.  To re-emphasize: not always the most elegant solution, but occasionally the most practical.  Use other solutions if you can.